# Память, занимаемая процессом и память, занимаемая процессом в диспетчере

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

1) Что за значение показывает диспетчер задач ? Private Working Set. Это сумма страниц памяти, которая имеет статус COMMITTED ?

2) Программно можно ли получить данное значение ? Есть две структуры для GetProcessMemoryInfo, но у них нет такого параметра.

3) Если нельзя, то откуда эту информацию берет сам диспетчер ?

```
typedef struct _PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX {
  DWORD  cb;
  DWORD  PageFaultCount;
  SIZE_T PeakWorkingSetSize;
  SIZE_T WorkingSetSize;
  SIZE_T QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T PagefileUsage;
  SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
  SIZE_T PrivateUsage;
} PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX, *PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX;

typedef struct _PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS {
  DWORD  cb;
  DWORD  PageFaultCount;
  SIZE_T PeakWorkingSetSize;
  SIZE_T WorkingSetSize;
  SIZE_T QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T PagefileUsage;
  SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
} PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS, *PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS;

GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProcess, (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS *)&pmc, sizeof(pmc));
```

Comment: `PrivateUsage` - это не оно? Через WMI можно получать самую разную информацию. Но его использование в C++ весьма коряво.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет, это значение, к слову, совпадает с PageFileUsage, но именно Private Working Set не является. почти в два  раза больше